# What is the use of the GetClipboardViewer function from WinAPI?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, user32

I'm trying to understand and learn some useful things about WinAPI and I just can't find the use of the of the GetClipboardViewer function nor some extensive documentation. Is there an example that uses the GetClipboardViewer function written in C?

Comment: Did you find the extensive [Using the Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dataxchg/clipboard)?

Comment: Yes, yes. The MSDN documentation is really extensive, but there isn't a single example that uses the GetClipboardViewer function, sadly. @WeatherVane

Comment: [This page](https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/viewchm.php/hs/petzold.chm/petzoldi/ch12d.htm) shows some code fragments and says: *Windows also has a function that allows a program to obtain the window handle of the first clipboard viewer: `hwndViewer = GetClipboardViewer () ;` **This function isn't normally needed**.* (my bolding)

Comment: Note that the docs for `SetClipboardViewer` say you shouldn't use it any more. I would guess the same applies to the `Get` function as well. *The SetClipboardViewer function exists to provide backward compatibility with earlier versions of Windows. The clipboard viewer chain can be broken by an application that fails to handle the clipboard chain messages properly. New applications should use more robust techniques such as the clipboard sequence number or the registration of a clipboard format listener.*

Comment: Yes. I am well aware of that, but I have an assignment to research some Windows API functions related to the clipboard and, even though it's outdated, the function is still relevant when analysing code written for earlier version of Windows. Thank you for your help, @JonathanPotter

Comment: Thank you. That page has been most helpful. @WeatherVane

Comment: @WeatherVane +1, but you probably ment [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard) link.

Comment: @Christian.K that's in the more general clipboard page I linked in my first comment (of two).